# How to use selenium sending keys to the hideNameInput?

Tags: python, selenium, input

Below is the HTML elements, I want input something into the span `id="nameNoteId"`.

```
<span onclick="hideNameInput()" id="nameNoteId">Username</span>
```

Below is the codes.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

url = 'http://passport2.chaoxing.com/login?fid=1479&refer=http://i.mooc.chaoxing.com'

# driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
elem = driver.find_element_by_id('passwordId')
elem.send_keys('something')
not_work_elem = driver.find_element_by_id('nameNoteId')
not_work_elem.click()
not_work_elem.send_keys('test')

driver.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`send_keys()` does not work here because it is `span` element. If you want to change `span` content you should try using `execute_script()` as below :-

```
not_work_elem = driver.find_element_by_id('nameNoteId')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].textContent = arguments[1]", not_work_elem, "test")
```

**Edited**:- After seeing your website when `clicked` on span `hideNameInput()` function called which provided the focus on `unameId` input and hides the visible `span`, So  you should try as below :-

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = 'http://passport2.chaoxing.com/login?fid=1479&refer=http://i.mooc.chaoxing.com'

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

span = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "nameNoteId")))
span.click()

unameId = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "unameId")))
unameId.send_keys('test')

passwordId = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "passwordId")))
passwordId.send_keys('CNM')
```

Hope it helps...:)

Comment: I didn't mean to change the span content.But sending keys into the input,and login in the website.

Comment: How can i do that?

Comment: @panda0 Then you need to specify it in your question..your question is not clear and provide then login form HTML..

Comment: @panda0 share your HTML where you want to `send_keys`

Comment: @panda0 i got it try with the updated answer...it works..:)